# Create an Appointment Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I would like to add event to calendar using Outlook e-mail. For me and for other user but I have got problem to logging in.

**My application is a web-based**

[image]

I found a nice example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff184629(v=office.15).aspx

```
private void AllDayEventExample()
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = Application.CreateItem(
        Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    appt.Subject = "Developer's Conference";
    appt.AllDayEvent = true;
    appt.Start = DateTime.Parse("6/11/2007 12:00 AM");
    appt.End = DateTime.Parse("6/16/2007 12:00 AM");
    appt.Display(false);
}
```

**My Account**

Login: Rafal

Password: 12345678

Domain: Test

Email: rafal@ss.ss

Outlook Website: https://mail.ss

Friend email: jhon@ss.ss

**I found also this but I don`t know how to use it to logging in**

```
// If not, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.
                application = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                nameSpace.Logon("", "", "", "");
                nameSpace = null;
```

Comment: The example is for the desktop version of Outlook, and it uses Windows credentials (more specifically, the Windows account that the process initializing the API is running as). I'm not sure if you can use it for the Web-based control...

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Do you have any idea how to connect to the email server?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I've only used the desktop API.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I know that the desktop version is very simple to use but I need a web version. Later I would like to import also calandar.

Comment: what is Application.createItem
it is giving me error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael,

You can use the Exchange Web Services to make this happen:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c

If you happen to be on Office 365 (which I doubt based on the screenshot above), you can use the Office 365 APIs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations