# Outlook in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get my ASP.NET website,hosted in IIS on a local server, to send a Outlook appointment item. However, I have encountered this error. I have tried the solutions provided by others online, but it still does not work.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

This is the line that was highlighted:

`Line 152:        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();`

Any form of help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1629c4b4-805e-41f1-b078-f1f0e4783397/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-outlook?forum=vbinterop - check this out maybe will help

Comment: have you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976082/create-an-appointment-outlook)